# Is there an Apache Calcite adapter for BigQuery

Tags: apache-calcite

Is there an Apache Calcite adapter for BigQuery which can translate Calcite SQL to BigQuery operations.

I am planning to use Apache Calcite for a unified query solution which can interact with heterogenous data sources and leverage its query optimization and query push down capabilities.